# Calculate the percentage of missing values per column using R

Tags: r

I'm working with a data frame that has about 1000 columns (variables) and 64000 lines. I need to know the percentage of missing values for each one of the columns and the total percentage of missing values of the entire data frame.

Does any one know the more efficient way to do that using R?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Reading this shall get you more productive answers, tho' the above comment puts you well on your way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to check the VIM package for visualising and inspecting missing data.

Answer (score 6):

One approach would be to convert your data frame into long format using `tidyr::gather` and then to apply a similar calculation to each column after grouping.

Supposing a data frame (smaller than yours for illustrative purposes):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
column = rep(paste0("col_", str_pad(1:1000, 4, pad = "0")), each = 640),
value = sample(c(0:100, NA_integer_), replace = TRUE, 6.4E5),
line = rep(1:640, 1E3)
) %>% spread(column, value)
```

Convert to long with tidyr::gather, then group_by, and summarize to get the average missingness by column:

```
df %>%
gather(col, value, -line) %>%
group_by(col) %>%
summarize(missing_share = mean(is.na(value)))

    # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
   col      missing_share
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 col_0001       0.0109 
 2 col_0002       0.0141 
 3 col_0003       0.0125 
 4 col_0004       0.00938
 5 col_0005       0.0141 
 6 col_0006       0.00625
 7 col_0007       0.00312
 8 col_0008       0.00781
 9 col_0009       0.00781
10 col_0010       0.00781
# ... with 990 more rows
```

Or skip the grouping step to get overall missingness:

```
df_NA_overall <- df %>%
gather(col, value, -line) %>%
summarize(missing_share = mean(is.na(value)))

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  missing_share
          <dbl>
1       0.00989
```

The first part can be done yet faster using `purrr::map`:

```
map(df, ~mean(is.na(.))) 

$line
[1] 0

$col_0001
[1] 0.0109375

$col_0002
[1] 0.0140625

$col_0003
[1] 0.0125

$col_0004
[1] 0.009375

$col_0005
[1] 0.0140625

$col_0006
[1] 0.00625

$col_0007
[1] 0.003125

$col_0008
[1] 0.0078125

$col_0009
[1] 0.0078125
```

Comment: Hi, Jon! Many thanks for your great solution. It worked the way I expected.